# Is there any possible way to get from mp4 file path to get only the audio object in python?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, signal-processing, librosa

I am trying to make a signal processing on audio signal and I am trying to skip the process of extracting first the audio from the mp4 file. There is any way to get the audio object directly from mp4 file using librosa or ffmpeg ?

Comment: Please post any code you have tried so far.

Comment: librosa.load('file.mp4')